# How can I sum a single key in an array of data objects linked by one property?

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

I've got an array of objects with a key of pNum as an identifier. There is a second key titled "value". I would like to combine all entries with the same pNum and sum their value. Example below.

**Input**

```
[
    {
        "pNum": 1,
        "value": 56
    },
    {
        "pNum": 2,
        "value": 49
    },
    {
        "pNum": 1,
        "value": 73
    }
]
```

**Output**

```
[
    {
        "pNum": 1,
        "value": 129
    },
    {
        "pNum": 2,
        "value": 49
    }
]
```

Comment: You should clarify what is the expected output. If the second array is the expected output please say so explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

Used [dw playground](https://developer.mulesoft.com/learn/dataweave/) and attaching DW code to transform the required output below.

Logic is to first do a groupBy and then use arithmetic operation to sum total values.

```
 %dw 2.0
output application/json
---
(payload groupBy ((item, index) -> item.pNum)) pluck ((value, key, index) ->{
    pNum: key,
    "value": sum(value."value")
} )
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The logic will be to groupBy pNum and sum the value , if the requirement is using pNum as Number, use as below:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
payload groupBy $.pNum pluck {
  pNum: $[0].pNum,
  value: sum($.value)
}
```